# Weird Behaviour With BearSSL on GPIO esp8266

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, gpio

I use GPIO 5 to trigger a relay, my code also connects with a secure MQTT connection for which I have to use the BearSSL certificate definitions.
Without the BearSSL certificates, when the esp restarts it does not re-trigger the relay, and the GPIO maintains its' state between reboots, but when I use the bearSSL certificates the behavior changes, and GPIO 5 goes low on restart. Any explanation why and how to mitigate it?
I am 100% sure it is because of the import, cause I removed components of my code until I could find the piece of code that causes this, and it was because of the declarations.

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h> 
static const char AWS_CERT_CA[] PROGMEM = R"EOF( 
aws root)EOF"; 
 
static const char AWS_CERT_CRT[] PROGMEM = R"KEY(
device cert)KEY";
 
static const char AWS_CERT_KEY[] PROGMEM = R"KEY(
device key )KEY";
 
BearSSL::X509List cert(AWS_CERT_CA);
BearSSL::X509List client_crt(AWS_CERT_CRT);
BearSSL::PrivateKey key(AWS_CERT_KEY);
 
WiFiClientSecure espClient;
void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  ESP.restart();
 }

void loop() {}
Without the following three lines

BearSSL::X509List cert(AWS_CERT_CA); 
BearSSL::X509List client_crt(AWS_CERT_CRT); 
BearSSL::PrivateKey key(AWS_CERT_KEY);
```

The LED on GPIO 5 does not flicker on restarts but adding these lines makes them flicker. Any solution or suggestion towards a solution for this problem will be really helpful.